# PHP or Javascript - How can i automate the download info from csv and show on webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a webservice link . e.g www.xyz.com/abcdefg, when i go to this link, it will download a csv file..

CSV file will show the data in columns like below;

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
test1          1           5           9
test2          2           6           10
test3          3           7           11
test4          4           8           12
```

I would like to automate the process on every day 7:00 in the morning and the above data will show when I go to another weblink called www.test.com

I would like to achieve this task through php or javascript. Please help, I need a complete code. Thanks

Comment: first part is to use cron

Answer (score 0):

The main process:

1. Use `cron` to run the download job.
2. Analyze and storage the data in your server ( by way of file or sql)
3. When you go to xyz.com, the background code will read the data saved and give it to you.

Have a good try!

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to achieve is something that two separate scripts can achieve. Assuming you mean 7am and you're using bash, you'd run

```
crontab -e
```

Then put in:

```
* 7 * * * /your/command
```

Where /your/command is the code needed to run daily for the CSV file. The secondary script would be your web server code that would simple grab the CSV file in its current state for presentation.